# How can I have colored emoji in URxvt?

Tags: arch-linux, colors, fonts, rxvt, emoji

Let me first clarify that `xfce4-terminal` does show colored emojis on the very same system for which I ask the question.

URxvt, on the other hand, doesn't show them. Based on [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts#Emoji_and_symbols),

> Emojis should work without any configuration once you have at least one emoji font installed of supported format.

but apperently that's not the case for me.

You can see in the following screenshot the different behaviuor of the two terminal emulators (in the top left there's the `.Xdefaults` file used to configure URxvt)
[image]

If I change the line

```
URxvt*font:             xft:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono:size=12
```

to

```
URxvt*font:             xft:NotoEmoji Nerd Font Mono:style=Book:size=12
```

I obtain non-colored emojis shown in a very ugly font where some characters are ok (the two emojis and the digits) and others are terribly pixelated (the letters):

[image]

What can I do to make URxvt show colored emoji?

Answer (score 0):

URxvt does not currently support colored emojis.

Comment: Ehm, where do I read this info?

Comment: @Enlico I asked on their [official IRC channel](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.libera.chat/?&theme=cli#rxvt-unicode).

Comment: What happens if you delete everything after `xft:DejaVuSansMono` ? Does that fix your problem?