# How should I interpret the fact that a Unicode code point is shown in two completely different ways in two different terminal emulators?

Tags: fonts, unicode, terminal-emulator, standard

This is kind of a spin off from [an older question I asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715076/how-can-i-have-colored-emoji-in-urxvt).

Here's the screenshot from that question:
[image]

- In the bottom left is [URxvt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rxvt-unicode), and you can see a lighting bolt-like icon at the beginning of the prompt, that's `"\ue00a"`;
- in the bottom right is `xfce-terminal` from [Xfce](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xfce), and you can see that it renders the very same `"\ue00a"` Unicode point in a very different way!

I was under the impression that when I read something like `"\ue00a"`, `"\u263b"`, `"\u1d43d"` and so on, I'm most likely looking at the identity of a symbol, as defined by Unicode.

However, how strange would the definition need to for it to allow 2 terminal emulators to show it so differently?

Incidentally, I don't know how much of this is due to the terminals and how much to the fonts.

I am asking this question (like the other I linked) in order to get a better understanding of the whole matter.

Comment: "I read something like "\ue00a", "\u263b", "\u1d43d" and so on, I'm most likely looking at the identity of symbol, as defined by Unicode", sure, but the font determines what that synbol looks like. The font can show pretty much anything, see, e.g., [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings), or less famously the [Powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)

Comment: Related: [Why are these fancy characters not shown in my prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320735)

Comment: It would be great if the OP could add a codeblock with the problematic `echo` lines. That way readers can cut-and-paste into their own terminals. Also, am I to understand that the central question is about a (terminal-specific) custom prompt? Thx.

Answer (score 16):

[U+E000 to U+F8FF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf) is a [private-use area](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html). It's reserved to allow systems to store and display characters that are not present in Unicode. So you can't expect it to have a consistent appearance (or indeed to appear as anything other than a blank space or [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character)).

If you want a lighting-like character in Unicode, you can try drawing it on [Shapecatcher](https://shapecatcher.com/) (but it doesn't know all of Unicode, especially not Emoji), or search through [Unicode character names](https://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html). I can't find a lightning bolt character exactly like the one in your screenshot, but there's U+26A1 HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN (⚡) and U+1F5F2 LIGHTNING MOOD () which are visually close. There are meteorological symbols U+2607 LIGHTNING (☇), U+2608 THUNDERSTORM (☈) and U+26C8 THUNDER CLOUD AND RAIN (⛈) which are semantically related but visually very different.

Comment: See also `unicode --max 0 --regex lightning` from the `unicode` Debian package.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146102/discussion-on-answer-by-gilles-so-stop-being-evil-how-should-i-interpret-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.